# How to determine if a relation is an equivalence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

So I am trying to figure out which of these are equivalence relations. I think I understand the basic idea in the sense that I need to check and see if each one is reflexive, transitive, and symmetric, but I am unsure of how to proceed with these particular relations. Any ideas here?

1.) Let $A$ be a set and $B$ be a subset of $A$. Define $R$ on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ by $X ~R~ Y$ iff $X \cap B = Y \cap B$.

2.) Define $R$ on $\mathbb{N}$ by $m ~R~ n$ iff $2 | mn$.

Comment: What does it mean for $R$ to be reflexive in the specific examples?  Is it true?  Same questions for symmetry and transitivity.

Comment: @saulspatz Am I correct in thinking #2 is not reflexive or transitive? I'm still stuck on #1 though. Do I need to figure out what P(A) is first?

Comment: $P(A)$ is a standard notation for the Power Set of $A$. That is, $P(A)=\{C: C\subseteq A\}.$

Comment: Right, but would P(A) = {emptyset, A, B}? Or is there more to it then that?

Comment: You are correct that #2 is not reflexive, e.g. $m=n=1$. And corrext that $R$ is  not transitive in #2, e.g. if $m=n=1$ and $p=2$ then $mRp\land pRn$ but \neg (mRn)$.

Comment: What about the first one? How am I to think about this one? I imagine I need to figure out what P(A) is specifically, but I'm not sure if P(A) = {emptyset, A, B} or if there are more subsets that I am not thinking of.

Comment: $P(A)$ has nothing to do with $B$.... $P(A)$ is just the set of $all$ subsets of $A$ (including $A$ because $A$ is a subset of $A$.)

Comment: But if B is given as a subset of A would that not make B an element of P(A)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120810/discussion-between-jonc2006-and-danielwainfleet).

Answer (score 0):

Definitions are not ornaments. They are the tools to be used. "Reflexive, symmetric, transitive" are merely the $names$ of the tools.

$R$ is reflexive iff $(\bullet)\;\forall x\, (xRx).$

$R$ is symmetric iff $(\bullet\bullet)\;\forall x,y\,(xRy\implies yRx).$

$R$ is transitive iff $(\bullet\bullet\bullet)\;\forall x,y,z\,(\,[xRy\land yRz]\implies xRz).$

So which, if any, of $(\bullet),(\bullet\bullet),(\bullet\bullet\bullet)$ are true?

Someone else on this site said "Definitions are your friends".

For 1). Reflexive: If $x\subseteq A,$ let $y=x.$ Then $xRx \iff xRy \iff x\cap B=y\cap B\iff x\cap B=x\cap B.$

Symmetric: If $x,y\subseteq A$ let $x'=y$ and $y'=x.$ Then $$xRy\implies x\cap B=y\cap B\implies$$ $$\implies x'\cap B=y\cap B=x\cap B=y'\cap B\implies x'Ry'\implies yRx.$$

Transitive: $[xRy\land yRz]\implies$ $ [x\cap B=y\cap B\,\land \, y\cap B=z\cap B]\implies$ $\implies [x\cap B=y\cap B=z\cap B]\implies$ $ [x\cap B=z\cap B]\implies xRz.$

Comment: But that is what I am confused on, I don't get how to think about these definitions for these particular relations. I get the basic definitions for reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, but I am not seeing how to think about how to figure out if the given relations meet the criteria for each.

Comment: I have expanded my Answer.